# Asp.Net create static HTML file from dynamic page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have a CSS folder and I want that when I build the project it should be copied to my build folder. I know I can do this using Post Build events. However I don't know how to achieve the following:

I have an action `/MyController/DynamicPage` I want that when I build my project this action's method must execute dynamically and spit out the HTML generated by executing the URL in DynamicPage.html

I want this to happen on building the project / solution. I explored `Build Events` but I am not sure if `post build event` can help me execute this type of custom code. Is there any way to achieve the above?

Thanks so much.

Comment: You can run any arbitrary cmd line statement in your build event... You could have a console app that does what you need and call it?

Answer (score 0):

> I have a CSS folder and I want that when I build the project it should be copied to my build folder

If this folder is included to your VS project,it will automatically get copied to your build output folder.

> I have an action /MyController/DynamicPage I want that when I build my project this action's method must execute dynamically and spit out the HTML generated by executing the URL in DynamicPage.html

if you want to happen with build,you should probably write a custom build task ,check [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/msbuild/2006/01/21/how-to-implementing-custom-tasks-part-i/) for more details

If you do not want to do this but would like to achieve the same after deployment(assuming your website runs inside IIS or IIS Express),You can also look at [Application Initialization Module](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-initialization) .With Application initialzation,IIS server will make sure when the application is deployed and started ,it will make a request to a configurable URL (in this case /MyController/DynamicPage) .Please have a look at [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/01/07/configure-the-iis-application-initialization-module/) .

What you can do is set the **path** [image: app initilzation module]

Comment: I will checkout however there is no build folder. I think you have mistaken it for Bin / Debug folder. I want to copy to *build* folder or let's say an arbitary folder named *dist*

Comment: sorry  I did not get it.you have a project which you would like to build, the build directory will be your project directory only. You do not copy the project files somewhere and build it ?

Comment: You have a confusion. Nowhere did I say build is my project directory. Build means Building the solution in Visual Studio.

Comment: that is correct.when you build ,your build directory will be same as your project's directoy.if you like to copy some files from other location to project directory( before or after build ),you can use <Target Name="BeforeBuild">  <Copy SourceFiles="" DestinationFolder="" />

Comment: I think you still don't follow. Rohith I want a folder named "build" inside that my css folder should be copied. It would be done using xcopy $(ProjectDir) I hope you are clear. Build is my directory names. My projects name is XYZ CSS folder is CSS and Building the project means building the solution in Visual Studio.